# How do I remove this blue selection background in a TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, blend

Print screen:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/253/bluebackground.png/

I have a treeViewItem and when I click on it, this damn blue selection appear inside it! Ive already tried to get the trigger isSelected in style. But doesnt SOLVE!

Help please!

Comment: Can you please post some of the code so we know what you've done and how its setup?

Comment: You are clearly frustrated but that's your problem. You won't engender much sympathy with phrases like "how the hell", "damn blue selection" etc. And are we just meant to guess what this thing is? You know what it is? Instead of ranting how about calming down and spending some time explaining your problem?

Comment: Yes some code would help. It does not look like a regular TreeViewItem selection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh the rage.

```xml
<TreeView.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">
        Transparent
    </SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}">
        Black
    </SolidColorBrush>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: HELL YEA! THANKS! YOU ARE A VERY GOOD PERSON!